# Is PowerShell 5 supported in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I have just read the following that seems to indicate PowerShell 5 is not supported in SharePoint 2013.  Can someone clarify?

> Second, most of the code written in earlier versions of PowerShell
>   will work on version 5.0 but the latest version is sufficiently
>   different that problems can arise, mostly with external dependencies.
>   These will be things like SharePoint or other software that hasn’t
>   been updated to support PowerShell 5.0.

Comment: What is the source of that reference? I am using 5 without any issues.

Comment: A book called learning Powershell Scripting

Comment: hmm indeed there have been some incompatibility reported. https://www.jaapbrasser.com/tag/powershell-5-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the 5.0 had some issues with Exchange and SharePoint. I am using 5.1 for about year and half now on 8 farms environment and we haven't hit any issues. We even automated the CU process using PS. We use PS very extensively for admin and release deployment. Main reason to move to 5.1 were improvements in the DSC.

The release notes for 5.1 do not mention any incompatibility:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/whats-new/release-notes